# how to integrate elaqua form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to integrate external elaqua form(external form) in wordpress site.I have elaqua form source code.I want to integrate this elaqua contact form in wordpress.
How to integrate elaqua form in WordPress 4.7.7

Answer (score 0):

**Steps For To embed a form in a web page:**

1. Navigate to Assets [image: An image of the Assets icon, which is represented by a black pencil.], then click Forms.
2. [Open an existing form](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60665_01/marketingcs_gs/OMCAA/Help/Forms/Tasks/EditingForms.htm), or [create a new one](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60665_01/marketingcs_gs/OMCAA/Help/Forms/Tasks/CreatingForms.htm).
3. Click **Actions** [image: An image of the Actions button, which is represented by two small black arrows pointing to the right.], then select **View Form HTML** to open the Form Integration Details window.

[image]

4. Copy any styles in your form and paste them into the header of your external web page's code. Then copy the rest of the form after  and paste it where you'd like the form to appear in the body of the external page.
5. Click the **Integration Details** tab, then copy the tracking scripts into the web page.

[image]

- Required tracking script HTML for this form: Copy this script and paste it to the bottom of your form before the .
- Required hidden tracking fields for this form: Copy these fields and paste them after the hidden fields at the top of your form body HTML.

[image]

**Note: First party cookies must be enabled by a customer administrator.**

You can check your form submission data by navigating to **Actions >> Form Submission Data** to ensure your form has been embedded properly.

Comment: which plugin I have to use

Comment: where to find assets as you describe in 1st step?

Comment: Did you use any plugin??

Comment: contact 7 form and 3rd party services

Comment: you can use Gravity Form for this functionality. Follow the link for Integrate Eloqua into Gravity Forms -  https://github.com/solepixel/gravityforms-eloqua